# How to get databases list and user having access to it in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I'm using PHP SSH library and trying to get list of database with users having lists to it.

Currently way I can find is

```
show databases
```

then run foreach for each user to see if it has access to the database which can take ages to complete for bit long databases and users.

How can I make it more efficient or other work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.db WHERE Db = '<database name in LC>'\G;
```

The `\G` is to get results displayed in a more readable format.

If you want only to get the `Db` and `User` fields you can then:

```
SELECT Db, User FROM ...
```

Comment: Is there's a way to avoid all unnecessary information beside Db and User from this command.

Comment: Yes, you can SELECT only the fields you want to show: `SELECT Db, User FROM ...`